# Ajax implementation in sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, ajax, sharepoint

I was trying to implement ajax in my sharepoint site.I am following this blog..

http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/mike/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=3

I did changes in the default webconfig file.But when i kept script manager in my sharepoint masterpage using sharepoint designer then it  is showing error as script manager is not permitted.
Can anyone help me in implementing ajax in sharepoint site.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the relevant ASP.NET code and the exact error message you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that applies to pages developed with Visual Studio, not SharePoint Designer.

The Microsoft AJAX components are designed around server side code with some client side functionality - ie you have to develop server side code, which requires codebehind files.

While it is possible to modify web.config and allow script blocks in designer edited pages, I wouldn't recommend it. For Ajax functionality when you can only change client side script it's best to use jQuery, which has no server side dependencies.